# Regex to match every occurence of a character except the first one

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex that will match a `=` after the last occurrence of a closing bracket.

So in those examples, it should match :

```
=FUNCTION(LABEL="TEST")=
                       ^ this
```

```
=FUNCTION(LABEL="TEST")===
                       ^^^ this
```

How can I write a regex that follows this requirement?

Comment: So which is it do you want: A regex that matches every occurrence but the first, or a regex that matches only after the last `)`?

Comment: A regex that matches every occurrence of a "=" after the last ")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookahead:

```
=(?=[^)]*$)
```

...in which `[^)]*$` ensures that there are no closing bracket following it until the end of string.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/S3Cqlr/1).

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

console.log('=FUNCTION(LABEL="TEST")='.match(/=(?=[^)]*$)/));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
/(?<=\)(?=[^\)]*$).*)=/
```

If you want the `=` to be immediately after the bracket with no characters in between:

```
/(?<=\)(?=[^\)]*$))=/
```